# Do shorthand switch statements exist (in PHP)?

Tags: php, switch-statement, shorthand

I want to compare the same variable (or expression) with many different values, and return a different value depending on which value it equals to. I want to do this [inline or shorthand](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php), as is possible with an `if` statement.

Take the following [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
switch($color_name) {
    case 'red':
    case 'blue':
        $color_type = handlePrimaryColor($in);
        break;
    case 'yellow':
    case 'cyan':
        $color_type = handleSecondaryColor($in);
        break;
    case 'azure':
    case 'violet':
        $color_type = handleTertiaryColor($in);
        break;
    default:
        $color_type = null;
        break;
}
```

I don't like writing `$color_type =` in every case and would like to find a way to do this with less code.

I could do it with some form of shorthand syntax. Below, I use a [shorthand `if` statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) to assign a value to the variable in the same place where it is first being declared:

```
$color_type = $color_name == 'red' || $color_name == 'blue'
    ? handlePrimaryColor($color_name)
    : ($color_name == 'yellow' || $color_name == 'cyan'
        ? handleSecondaryColor($color_name)
        : ($color_name == 'azure' || $color_name == 'violet'
            ? handleTertiaryColor($color_name)
            : null
        )
    );
```

This method doesn't require declaring the variable within each construct, but gives me 2 new problems instead:

- I now have to write a new `OR` condition for each color
- Every group of conditions adds an extra level of nesting

My question: Is there a method which allows me to directly assign a value to a variable using shorthand syntax that behaves like a switch?

If there isn't, I would be interested in learning why that limitation exists.

Comment: I bet your colleagues love you

Comment: Why is that? I am just interested in learning if it's possible to translate my switch statement into a shorthand version. In reality I don't expose my colleagues to multi-level nested inline if statements. The subject and content of my code in the question only serve as an example.

Comment: It was just a light hearted comment - i have encountered code like that in the wild before, it was a depressing experience!

Comment: Hey taken lightly, I was only afraid someone might think I produce such code, while the purpose of my question is to avoid it :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since PHP 8.0 there is a shorthand switch available which is called **match**

```
$colorType = match($color) {
    'red', 'blue' => handlePrimaryColor($in),
    'yellow', 'cyan' => handleSecondaryColor($in),
    'azure', 'violet' => handleTertiaryColor($in),
    default => null
};
```

Comment: The semicolon should be at the end of the block, after curly bracket closed.

Comment: And there, my 8 year old question finally gets an accepted answer :)

Answer (score 5):

Too much work. Use a dispatch table.

```
$color_dispatch = Array(
  'red' => 'handlePrimaryColor',
  'blue' => 'handlePrimaryColor',
   ...
);

$color_type = null;
if (array_key_exists($color_name, $color_dispatch))
{
  $color_type = $color_dispatch[$color_name]($in);
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, but I think you want `isset($color_dispatch[$color_name])` or `array_key_exists`.  Check for the key not the value.

Comment: @AbraCadaver: Indeed. Fixed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but the intention of my question was to find out if such a method exists (like shorthand if statements exist) or learn about the limitations why such a thing can't/doesn't exist. I'm not looking for alternatives, but just curious.

Comment: It doesn't exist because everybody uses dispatch tables instead.